# How to implement followers/following in Django

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I want to implement the followers/following feature in my Django application.

I've an **UserProfile** class for every **User** (django.contrib.auth.User):

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique = True, related_name = 'user')
    follows = models.ManyToManyField("self", related_name = 'follows')
```

So I tried to do this in python shell:

```
>>> user_1 = User.objects.get(pk = 1) # <-- mark
>>> user_2 = User.objects.get(pk = 2) # <-- john
>>> user_1.get_profile().follows.add(user_2.get_profile())
>>> user_1.get_profile().follows.all()
[<UserProfile: john>]
>>> user_2.get_profile().follows.all()
[<UserProfile: mark>]
```

But as you can see, when I add a new user to the `follows` field of a user, is also added the symmetrical relation on the other side. Literally: if user1 follows user2, also user2 follows user1, and this is **wrong**.

Where's my mistake? Have you a way for implement followers and following correctly?

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Set [symmetrical](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical) to False in your Many2Many relation:

```
follows = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='follows', symmetrical=False)
```

Comment: What is the difference between symmetrical=False and related_name='fie+'?

Answer (score 17):

In addition to mouad's answer, may I suggest choosing a different *related_name*: If Mark **follows** John, then Mark is one of John's **followers**, right?