# Django, in many to many relationship within the self class, how do I reference each other in terms of ORM?

Tags: django, django-models, orm, many-to-many, m2m

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    gender = models.IntegerField()
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    following = models.ManyToManyField("self", related_name='followers')
    objects = UserManager()
    def __repr__(self):
        return "User: {0}".format(self.name)
```

In my model, User, users can follow and followed by each other.

I can find who the user is following by this:

```
user1 = User.objects.get(id=1)
following = user1.following.all()
```

However, I can't figure out how to find whom the user is followed by.

I tried:

```
user1.followers.all()
```

since it is the related_name in the following field in my model.

Can anybody please teach me how to do this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement followers/following in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218175/how-to-implement-followers-following-in-django)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should pass the [`symmetrical`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical) attribute to be `False`.

From the docs:

> When Django processes this model, it identifies that it has a `ManyToManyField` on itself, and as a result, it doesn’t add a `followers` attribute to the `User` class. Instead, the `ManyToManyField` is assumed to be symmetrical – that is, if I am your `follower`, then you are my `follower`.
>
> **If you do not want symmetry in many-to-many relationships with `self`, set `symmetrical` to `False`**. This will force Django to add the descriptor for the reverse relationship, allowing `ManyToManyField` relationships to be non-symmetrical.

In your case:

```
class User(models.Model):
    # ...
    following = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='followers', symmetrical=False)
    # ...
```

Then in your `views.py` you can access both:

```
following = user.following.all()
followers = user.followers.all()
```

Since now the relationship with `self` is non-symmetrical.

Comment: Any idea on how I avoid following being the same as follower? I mean, how to avoid a User following himself with that approach? Thanks.

Comment: I managed to achieve something with this code inside `User` model:
`def safe_following(self): return self.following.exclude(id=self.pk)`
but I'd like to create a field constraint that would avoid self following when saving the data.