# How to query reverse many to many in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model Profile (user's profile) and it has many to many relation to self named followings.  This manages followers / followings system like one in twitter.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    followings = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank = True, related_name = 'followers')
```

I can get followings just get followings of an User but how to query followers of a user using django model query?

Comment: I've never been able to make sense of many to many fields. sorry.

Comment: @Bigair I would recommend you to use this plugin instead https://github.com/revsys/django-friendship

Comment: simply use the related name `followers`, e.g. assume you have a `p = Profile.objects.last()`, then `p.followers.all()` returns a queryset of all related objects to the object `p`

Comment: I got 'Profile' object has no attribute 'followers' error

Comment: Check the following article:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45847930/django-in-many-to-many-relationship-within-the-self-class-how-do-i-reference-e